# Retrieve values as list from stored procedure and bind it using BeanPropertyRowMapper to a model class

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures

I need to retrieve List of values as output from stored procedure.
I was using JDBC Template and everything was working fine, now I am trying to convert the whole thing to stored procedure format. But I am not sure how to fetch the values and display it in my JSP page.

This is my **Stored Procedure class**.

```
public class ListRegistration extends StoredProcedure {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private static final String SCHEMA_NAME = "ehr";
    private static final String SPROC_NAME = "ehr.usp_ListRegistration";

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public ListRegistration(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource, SPROC_NAME);
        declareParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet("rs", new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Patient.class)));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("LimitRows", Types.INTEGER));
        compile();
    }

    public List<Patient> spExecute(Integer LimitRows) {

        Map<String, Object> registrationResult = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        registrationResult = super.execute(LimitRows);
    //    List<Patient> employeeDetails = (List<Patient>) registrationResult.get(rs);
        List<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList(registrationResult.values());
        return patientList;
    }
}
```

Implementation part in **Implementation Class**

```
   public List<Patient> getPatient() {
        System.out.println("============================ Will Fetch Values ");
        List<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<Patient>();
     int t=100;
patientList=listRegistration.spExecute(100);
        return patientList;
    }
```

Where **Patient** is my **model class**.

My Controller Class

```
  @RequestMapping("/fetch-form")
    public ModelAndView fetchForm(Model model, Patient patient) {

        System.out.println("----------------------- Function Called -----------------------------------");
        List<Patient> patientList = patientService.getPatient();
        return new ModelAndView("patientList", "patientList", patientList);
    }
```

My JSP Page-to display the values that have been fetched

```
<body>
 <center> 
 <b>Patient's Complete List</b>

  <table border="1">
   <tr>
       <td class="heading">First Name</td>
    <td class="heading">Last Name</td>
    <td class="heading">Encounter Number</td>
    <td class="heading">MRN Number</td>
    <td class="heading">Last Visited Date</td>
    <td class="heading">Edit</td>

   </tr>
   <c:forEach var="patient" items="${patientList}">
    <tr>
     <td>${patient.firstName}</td>

     <td>${patient.lastName}</td>
     <td>${patient.encounterKey}</td>
     <td>${patient.patientMRNumber}</td>
     <td>${patient.metaUpdatedDT}</td>



   <td><a href="edit?patientKey=${patient.patientKey}">Edit</a></td>
    </tr><tr></tr>
   </c:forEach>
   <tr><td colspan="7"><a href="pre-reg">New Patient Registration</a></td></tr>
  </table>

 </center>
</body>
```

The error I am getting is

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'firstName' not found
on type java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: Not sure for what reason someone has tagged to close this post. If at all does it require to close, kindly mention the reasons as a comment.

Comment: @Polppan: It wasn't me but I can imagine that it's unclear. The OP seems to want to replace JDBC template by SP and I can't see how it's related to JSP. Moreover, there's a lot of code and it all at the first glance looks like it's working. Where's the problem?

Comment: it's with the Stored Procedure Class, I want the values coming from database to be assigned to List so that I can return it.

Comment: @maartinus: This is the error I am getting javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'firstName' not found on type java.lang.Integer

Comment: @north_head Kindly edit your question and mention the errors you are having rather than add as a comment. Adding your errors as comment most likely would get unnoticed.

Comment: @maaartinus Yes I understand. OP has to be make question clear, however that is not the case, I never understood why people vote to close without providing proper reasons. It has happened to me as well :-(

Comment: @Polppan: thanks for the suggestion,I made changes to the question.

Comment: @north_head No problem, you are welcome. I also suggest to modify your  subject to be more specific about the error you are getting which would add more views for your question or problems.